# Android open wear-os app from mobile app notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I've an application for Android mobile and wear-os with same package name as companion app.
When their is notification came on Mobile for my App and Mobile is not in use then notification received on watch and I want to open watch app from this notification but their is an option on watch as `Show in phone` but their is no option to open companion app. Is their any option for open watch app from default notification received from mobile to watch?
Thank you